# Refer server nodes in Ignite

Tags: ignite

I have 3 Ignite nodes on server, and form my side one client node, which has IpFinder  to 3 nodes on server.

1. How to refer to i-th node?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: By Ignite.cluster().nodes() we can get all nodes in cluster.
and Ignite.cluster().nodes(UUID)   specific node,but I dont know my nodes UUIDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign an unique attribute value to each node on startup:

```
    <property name="userAttributes">
        <map>
            <entry key="my_attr" value="value1"/>
        </map>
    </property>
```

Then retrieve nodes with `ClusterGroup.forAttribute` method.

Answer (score 2):

Nodes are not assigned to a particular index. So there is no API that will let you get i-th node.

However you can use tons of `ClusterGroup` API methods that allow to get nodes basing on different parameters.

Finally, the full list of the nodes can be obtained using `ignite.cluster().nodes()`. Every node from this list contains UUID that is assigned to it. It means that you can determine UUID of every node and use `ignite.cluster().node(uuid)` later.